# How to paint the region green?

Tags: r, polygon

Please see the attachment ,i want to paint the region which covers `R1` to be pink,
How can i paint it with `polygon`?

```
x = seq(-0.25, 2, by=0.01)
y1=x
y2=x^2
plot(x, y1,type="l",frame.plot=FALSE,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
lines(x,y2,type="l",col="red")
xx1<-c(0,x[x<1  & x>0 ],1)
yy1<-c(0,x[x<1  & x>0 ],0)
polygon(xx1,yy1,col="yellow")
xx1<-c(0,x[x<1  & x>0 ],1)
yy2<-c(0,(x[x<1  & x>0 ])^2,0)
polygon(xx1,yy2,col="blue")
## write some text
text(1.1,1,labels="y=x",col="black")
text(0.8,1,labels="y=x^2",col="red")
text(0.7,0.2,labels="R3",col="black")
text(0.4,0.35,labels="R2",col="black")
text(0.2,0.5,labels="R1",col="black")
## draw axes lines with arrows
arrows(min(x), 0, max(x), 0)
arrows(0, min(x), 0, max(x))
## add axes ticks
axis(1,at=c(0,0.5,1,1.5),pos=0)
axis(2,at=c(0,0.5,1,1.5),pos=0)
```

[image: i want to draw it]

[image]

Comment: R1 stops at `y=1`, right? wouldn't you just polygon the triangle `(0, 0) -- (0, 1) -- (1, 0)` ? much the same way as you coloured in `R3`?

Comment: Not sure that this is a duplicate of the above question - they have certainly worked out to shade the area between the two curves (i.e. know how to use `polygon`, it's just the remaining triangle they don't seem to be able to get (although i would have thought R2 was the hard part)

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the fact that shading the area R2 should have been the harder part (maybe this code was written by someone else?). The key ingredient is still to shade a region with `polygon()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just colour in the triangle  `(0, 0) -- (0, 1) -- (1, 1)` ?

```
polygon(c(0, 0, 1), c(0, 1, 1), col='pink')
```